# How to "describe" a class, index, or other object in OrientDB SQL?

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

Essentially, what is the "opposite" of CREATE CLASS (or CREATE anything) in ODB SQL? Most/all other SQL/SQL-like databases provide a way to describe a database object in terms of the SQL command it takes to create it, but I can't find anything about this in the ODB docs. What does Studio use when you click on a class in the Schema Manager? What I'm ultimately looking for is a way to produce the CREATE command from an existing database object, using ODB SQL.

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB schema can be queried to obtain information about classes:

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL.html#query-metadata

Information about classes:

```
select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

Information about a single class:

```
select expand(properties) from (
   select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
) where name = 'MyClassName'
```

Metadata about indexed could be obtained as well:

```
select expand(indexes) from metadata:indexmanager
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the metadata "class", but the output it produces can't be used to immediately recreate the underlying schema objects. What I was hoping for is a "two-way" solution, where ODB can describe its schema objects in terms that can be used to recreate them.

Comment: On that note, I'm considering an internal project to develop a tool that would use the metadata results to recreate the underlying schema objects. If we end up doing that, I'm happy to make it available to the ODB community.